# How does c# decoder know the exact number of bytes it should use for one char?

Tags: c#, .net, decoding

For example, a stream has four bytes: **D8 00 DC 05**. How does the decoder(e.g. `System.Text.Decoder`) know it should treat them as one char `\uD800\udc05` or two separate chars`\uD800` and `\udc05` please? Thanks.

Perhaps I didn't describe my question clearly. My original intention was about to understand how **UTF8** decoder knows the exact number of bytes it should use for one char, as one UTF8 char can take one to four bytes and the way to handle this variable is the magic. UTF16 decoder has no this problem for surrogate pairs. The above example is not appropriate for my question.

Comment: It is big-endian utf-16, code page 1201.  A very simple decoder, it just takes 2 bytes for every char.

Comment: Thanks Hans, could you please see my additional edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really about [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and ***surrogate pairs***.

The two ***code units*** U+D800 and U+DC05 always represent surrogate pairs. These two code units combine into one single code point, that is one character.

C# calls the code units `char` which can be a bit misleading since it sometimes takes two `char` values (a pair of surrogates) to create one "character", as you have noticed.

Any code unit (`char`) value between U+D800 and U+DBFF always represents the *lower* part of a surrogate pair, while any code unit between U+DC00 and U+DFFF is the corresponding *upper* part of the pair.

Code units outside this domain, i.e. either in U+0000 through U+D7FF or in U+E000 through U+FFFF stand for themselves, so in those ranges one UTF-16 code unit corresponds to one Unicode code point.

---

EDIT: The question was changed to ask about [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) instead.

I will use the word *octet* for a word of exactly 8 bits (so an octet is what most people call a *byte*).

In UTF-8 you can see from the position of the first 0 bit within the octet where this octet belongs in a UTF-8 sequence.

- `0xxxxxxx`: If the first bit is 0, this octet constitutes a **1**-octet sequence (ASCII value)
- `10xxxxxx`: If the octet starts on `10`, this is a continuation octet, i.e. not initial in the sequence
- `110xxxxx`: This is the initial octet in a **2**-octet sequence
- `1110xxxx`: This is the initial octet in a **3**-octet sequence
- `11110xxx`: This is the initial octet in a **4**-octet sequence

Since modern UTF-8 does not allow 5-octet sequences, or longer, it is illegal for an octet to start with five ones, `11111xxx`. But in early versions, the above scheme would be extended to allow 5-octet and 6-octet sequences (sometimes also longer).

---

When comparing UTF-16 and UTF-8, note that code points that require only a single 16-bit code unit in UTF-16, correspond exactly to code points that can be made with 1-, 2-, or 3-octet sequences in UTF-8. While code points that require a surrogate pair in UTF-16 (i.e. two UTF-16 code units) correspond exactly to those that require a 4-octet sequence in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe for your detailed answer. Could you please see my additional edit?

Comment: @DIB: UTF-8 works much the same way, certain bytes can never start a character, only follow, and the ones that can start a character are split into ranges depending on how many bytes follow.  Although [the Wikipedia article's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) isn't organized around these ranges, you can decode them easily from the bit patterns.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This means when the decoder reads the start byte, it is able to know how many bytes should follow based on the range that the start byte stays in.
On the other hand, a byte that represents a char(e.g. \u0041(Latin capital Letter A)) will never be a start byte of a char for two bytes,
and two bytes that represent a char will never be start bytes of a char for three bytes, etc.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @DIB I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks heaps Jeppe. Excellent and valuable answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is [.NET Framework source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) , you can look.

Source code of System.Text.Decoder placed [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/decoder.cs,58f76257700c46fa). So you can find here everything you want to know about your question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answerA link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.